# Entity Framework Cannot Save - Conversion Of Datetime2 To DateTime Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm running into an issue where a few of my Entity Framework entities are failing to save data. The error I get is

```
The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
```

I have a table called "Notes". It has a datetime field called "NoteDateTime". Here is a snippet of the SQL used to create the table. As you can see, the NoteDateTime field has nothing unusual about it.

```
CREATE TABLE [db].[Notes](
    [NoteID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NoteText] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [NoteDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsReviewRequired] [bit] NULL,
    [ConvertToGlobal] [bit] NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [EvaluationID] [int] NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [EmailID] [int] NULL,
    [AddedWhenMerged] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Notes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NoteID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

In my C# code, I populate a "Notes" entity and call the SaveChanges() method. The error occurs when I call SaveChanges().

```
dbContext.Notes.Add(new Note
{
    EvaluationID = evaluationId,
    CustomerID   = customerId,
    EmployeeID   = employeeId,
    NoteDateTime = DateTime.Now,
    NoteText     = noteText,
});

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I've read several stackoverflow threads and the advice was to ensure the proper date was being used and that the date should not be null. The date is not null and it is certainly within acceptable min/max limits. I also tried converting the type of the column to datetime2 in the database, but that didn't fix the issue. The bizarre thing is that this seems to be a recent issue. The only thing I can think of that changed in our environment is that we migrated our project to use MVC 4.

What can I do to troubleshoot this problem and get my Note entity to save properly?

Comment: Does Notes have any foreign key relationships that contain a not-null datetime? When I got hit with this last week I think it was either the DateTime was the default value (my ViewModel wasn't assigning correctly). It looks like you're setting it to DateTime.Now so this is unlikely the problem.

Comment: The Notes table has several foreign keys, but I don't think they are affecting the save.

Answer (score 1):

Julie Lerhman discusses this exact issue here (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Entity-Framework-Tips-and-Tricks), and trust me, she is the expert.

Myself, I'd make [NoteDateTime] nullable in your code like so

```
public DateTime? NoteDateTime { set; get; }
```

Comment: In Julie's video, she's using code-first tables. I'm using database-first tables. I'm not able to override the SaveChanges() method the way she did. Besides, her override method is used to populate a DateTime field in case its null before the save. In my case, I'm setting it to DateTime.Now and then saving the entity. Unfortunately, this video doesn't address my issue. The weird thing is that i changed it to a nullable field in the database and then tried it again and the value that gets saved to the database is null, even though I supplied a valid value.

Comment: yes, intercept the SQL emitted using SQL Profiles as Jaycee suggested to see what is being sent to the database. Also, try using tools like MiniProfiler or Glimpse to see what exactly Entity Framework is generating. If NULL is sent to the database, that is wrong - database first, you say?. Try regenerating the database model. I tried creating a table with your fields and saved the date succesfully. The problem is caused somewhere in those EDMX layers, perhaps, unless you have a trigger on the table.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned it, use Sql profiler to view the SQL being sent to the server. Try running the sql manually and see what error is returned.

Comment: A null value is being passed into the database, which explains the datetime2 error.